# How to reference maven project in general web app in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Below is a common web project in eclipse(not maven)
[image]

Below is a maven java project(not web).
[image]

I hope to reference the java app(webservices) in web app(showcase).
Currently I was packaging the java app with (mvn package) to generate the   **cloud-webservices-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar** and copy all the jars depended by webservices project to **showcase\war\WEB-INF\lib**. Is there any convenient method to implement this requirement? I know I can add the project in build path like below, but when I right click and run to server, the webservices.jar and other jars depended by webservices project will not be deployed.
[image]

Comment: if you are using the m2eclipse plugin the best way to do that is to just declare dependency in the webapp  pom.

Comment: you mean I need to convert the webapp to the maven project?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that your webapp wasn't a maven project, it's still an option. Anyway check my new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the dependent project to the deployment assembly of your web project. Frome the project properties choose the **Deployment Assembly** sheet then click the *Add* button and select your webservice project.

[image: screenshot]